# What does "standard-bearing" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "main"?

Leaving the euro is one of the FN's **standard-bearing** policies, both a mark of its anti-establishment stance that attracts voters angry with globalization, and a likely obstacle to its quest for power in a country where a majority oppose a return to the franc.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/26/france-marine-le-pen-euro-exit-wouldnt-be-chaos.html

Comment: "Main" is not wrong, but it's a bit more like their "hallmark" policy. In other words, they are known for this policy. Try looking up standard-bearer in Wikipedia and perhaps it will be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *standard* is a flag which is flown to identify something.

A *standard bearer* is the thing which "flies the flag" which identifies the something.  For example, each country's lead person in the Olympic procession is a *standard bearer* and helps identify their country.

In your example, a *standard-bearing* policy, is a policy that the party is known for and represents.